# Angular display response in HTML from Ajax GET

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax

Apologies in advance for asking a dumb question. I've related a dozen plus related posts without success.

Here's my controller.

```
app.controller('testController', function ($scope) {
    var myApi = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    $.ajax({
        url: myApi,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response[0]);
            $scope.response = response[0]
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log("could not retrieve list.");
            console.log(response.message);
        }
    });
});
```

My HTML is

```
<body ng-app="myApp" class="text-center">
    <div id="foo" ng-controller="testController">
        {{response.title}}
    </div>
...
</body>
```

And I can see in the browser console that I do get the desired content in the GET response

```
[Log] {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit", body: "quia et suscipit↵suscipit recusandae consequuntur …strum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"} (javascript.js, line 27)
```

...but the text doesn't show up in the rendered HTML. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here for posterity. I switched from Ajax to this $http method. As you can tell, I'm super brand new to this. If any seasoned experts are reading this, can you comment on the two approaches here and describe anything I'm probably missing?

```
app.controller('testController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data[0])
        $scope.response = response.data[0];
        console.log($scope.response)
        //alert($scope.response);
    });
});

<body ng-app="myApp" class="text-center">
    <div id="foo" ng-controller="testController">
        {{response.title}}
    </div>
...
</body>
```

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. The `$http` service is integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. The jQuery `.ajax` method is not.